# Code being reused over and over again, a more manageable way?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

So I noticed im starting to re-use code over and over again and its starting to look ugly. Each button click I noticed that some of the code (For POST) is the same apart from the uri. Is there any way I could manage the below code in a better way?

```
    private void AddTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uriAddTagtoGroup = string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AddTagtoGroup/{0}/{1}", textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);
        byte[] arr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uriAddTagtoGroup);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriAddTagtoGroup);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/xml";
        req.ContentLength = arr.Length;
        Stream reqStrm = req.GetRequestStream();
        reqStrm.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
        reqStrm.Close();
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        MessageBox.Show(resp.StatusDescription);
        reqStrm.Close();
        resp.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like code that can be trivially encapsulated in a method. Where is your problem? Something like `string ExecuteRequest(string uri)`

Comment: The URI would be a parameter to that method. Again: Where is your problem?

Comment: I think the problem is soon going to be sarky responses to a question lol

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Not really. The answer to this question is *so* trivial that I think I must have misunderstood or overlooked something or that he forgot to mention the one constraint that makes the trivial solution impossible, that's why I am asking him what the problem is.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Now that you have clarified it of course not. However without clarification it sounds sarky. And the fact that people are upvoting those types of comments is exacerbating the issue.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Well, Garrith's answer to CodeInChaos' question already sounded like a joke to me, that's why I renewed the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code can be pulled into a method with some parameters for the arguments that change:

```
private void AddTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uriAddTagtoGroup = string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AddTagtoGroup/{0}/{1}", textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);
    PerformPost(uriAddTagtoGroup);
}

public void PerformPost(string uri)
{
    byte[] arr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uri);
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/xml";
    req.ContentLength = arr.Length;
    Stream reqStrm = req.GetRequestStream();
    reqStrm.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
    reqStrm.Close();
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    MessageBox.Show(resp.StatusDescription);
    reqStrm.Close();
    resp.Close();
}
```

For disposable stuff (things that implement `IDisposable`), there is also the `using` keyword:

```
using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
{
    MessageBox.Show(resp.StatusDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out in the comments, just encapsulate it into a method:

```
private void AddTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uriAddTagtoGroup = 
       string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AddTagtoGroup/{0}/{1}",
          textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);
    RequestResponse(uriAddTagtoGroup)
}

private void RequestResponse(string uriAddTagtoGroup)
{
    byte[] arr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uriAddTagtoGroup);
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriAddTagtoGroup);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/xml";
    req.ContentLength = arr.Length;
    using(Stream reqStrm = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
       reqStrm.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
    }
    using(HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
       MessageBox.Show(resp.StatusDescription);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a static class, may be in a separate file and call it when you need to call the routine for post:

```
private void AddTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uriAddTagtoGroup = 
        string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AddTagtoGroup/{0}/{1}",
            textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);
    PostRoutine(uriAddTagtoGroup);        
}

public static void PostRoutine(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] arr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uri);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/xml";
        req.ContentLength = arr.Length;
        Stream reqStrm = req.GetRequestStream();
        reqStrm.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
        reqStrm.Close();
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        MessageBox.Show(resp.StatusDescription);
        reqStrm.Close();
        resp.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {    
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a method which accepts one parameter - the URI

```
private void AddTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string uriAddTagtoGroup = 
      string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AddTagtoGroup/{0}/{1}",
         textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);
   someMethod(uriAddTagtoGroup);
} 

private void someMethod(String uriAddTagtoGroup)
{
    byte[] arr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uriAddTagtoGroup);
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriAddTagtoGroup);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/xml";
    req.ContentLength = arr.Length;
    Stream reqStrm = req.GetRequestStream();
    reqStrm.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
    reqStrm.Close();
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    MessageBox.Show(resp.StatusDescription);
    reqStrm.Close();
    resp.Close();
}
```